# Discord bot online but not responding

Tags: discord.js, replit

I’m attempting to make a simple bot, but before I got into trying to fully make it I wanted to get it responding first but all the tutorials I’ve tried haven’t worked, I’m using Replit and I can get the bot to come online, but I can’t get any responses from it every way I’ve tried. What’s wrong is probably a really easy fix, but I’ve been unable to come across any solution that has worked, if not just break it more.

```
client = new Discord.Client({intents: 32767})

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
})

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith("ping")) {
    message.channel.send("pong!");
  }
});


client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

Comment: Is the `console.log()` in the `client.on('ready')` firing?

Comment: @Caladan yep it says the logged in thing in the console when I start the bot

Comment: Which version of `discord.js` do you have? You can find it in the `package.json` file

Comment: @Caladan it is ^14.5.0

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. But Discord recently started privileged intents. make sure you have enabled message content intent in your application's bot section. This will allow your bot to have access to reading message and its content. [More info](https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404772028055)

Comment: Thanks for the response ^^, though I already turned  the permission intents on and still no luck, attempted to get it to work by giving it admin but that also didn’t help and I’m unsure what to do from here lol

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm presuming that your using the latest version of Discord.js, being `discord.js@14.x.x`. In @14, the way that intents are used was changed.

**In `discord.js@13.x.x`**:

```js
const { Client } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({ intents: 32767 });
```

That would specify all of them, however, as of `discord.js@14.0.0`, this was changed to be like the following:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
  ]
});
```

I don't recommend using the Bitfield way of doing it, as it will become outdated overtime, and even then I don't know the Bitfield for it.

However, I will provide a list of the GatewayIntentBits, as well as a function to allow you to use Strings.

```
- GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageReactions
- GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageTyping
- GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages
- GatewayIntentBits.GuildBans
- GatewayIntentBits.GuildEmojisAndStickers
- GatewayIntentBits.GuildIntegrations
- GatewayIntentBits.GuildInvites
- GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers
- GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions
- GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageTyping
- GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages
- GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences
- GatewayIntentBits.GuildScheduledEvents
- GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates
- GatewayIntentBits.GuildWebhooks
- GatewayIntentBits.Guilds
- GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent
```

And for the function:

```js
function intents(...i) {
  const clientIntents = [];
  i.forEach(intent => {
    clientIntents.push(intent);
  });

  return clientIntents;
}
```

The reason this change was made is because Strings will eventually become overridden, and will have to be changed in accordance to the value in multiple places. With using an enum, they can easily change the value in one place, which affects all others, making development easier both on the discord.js developers, and the bot developers.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! It now works!! I’m surprised I haven’t heard anything about this change when I had spent all day looking into it but I’m now happy this part of the bot is settled :D

Comment: There are always other resources available such as the Discord.js Discord Server (https://discord.gg/djs), or the discord-api-types Documentation (https://discord-api-types.dev).